# Unicode weirdness with octopress, kramdown, and Heroku

Tags: heroku, unicode, octopress, kramdown

I have an [Octopress](http://octopress.org) blog that I host on Heroku using [jgarber's custom buildpack](https://github.com/jgarber/heroku-buildpack-ruby-octopress). I had things working fairly well as long as I stuck with [`rdiscount`](https://github.com/rtomayko/rdiscount), but I recently decided to switch to [`kramdown`](http://kramdown.rubyforge.org) for the [MultiMarkdown](http://fletcherpenney.net/multimarkdown/) support. That's when things got weird.

This works fine on my local box (OS X), but when I push to Heroku, I get the following error:

```
Liquid Exception: incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT in atom.xml
```

So far as I can tell, I'm UTF-8 through and through, but I'll readily admit that Ruby isn't my normal stack, so maybe I'm just missing something. I'm on `kramdown` v0.14.2. When I use `foreman run rake clean generate`, everything works, as does `bundle exec rake clean generate`. However, when I push to Heroku (or run `heroku run rake clean generate`), I get the error above.

I thought the issue might be something to do with the default encodings, so I performed the following experiment:

```
$ irb
1.9.3-p327 :001 > ENV["LANG"]
=> "en_US.UTF-8"
1.9.3-p327 :002 > Encoding.default_external
=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

and

```
$ heroku run irb
Running `irb` attached to terminal... up, run.6846
irb(main):001:0> ENV["LANG"]
=> "en_US.UTF-8"
irb(main):002:0> Encoding.default_external
=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

At this point, I'm all out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the `LC_CTYPE` env var too? Try `LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8`.

Comment: Sadly, that's been part of my `.profile` for years (I had to fix an issue with `svn` back in the day, and it's just hung around).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. My initial setup and deploy to GitHub worked fine. When I just edited the `_config.yml` and insert some Turkish characters like `ş`, I got a similar error. Adding system variables like `LANG` and `LC_ALL` did not help.

Then I just opened the file with notepad++, changed encoding to UTF-8 without BOM and the issue is solved. This also works for the post files (the ones with `.markdown` extensions in `source/_posts` folder)

So just change the file's encoding UTF-8 without BOM before inserting any non-ascii characters. There is no need for the environment variables.